# Why the secure boot blocked the wifi drivers

Tags: boot, networking, drivers, uefi, broadcom

Yesterday I was installing a Linux distro on friend computer and I was not able to enable the WiFi (Broadcom Limited BCM43142). I switched the drivers again and again and again, restarting the computer several times. I finally figured out why the WiFi was not available after an long investigation: the secure boot was not disable.

It finally works fine. But I would like to understand what happened under the hood at the hardware/software level. This is beyond my knowledge and my understanding and I would like to understand more how that works.

If this information is important, I installed the system in EFI mode.

Comment: Secure Boot requires all drivers to be signed properly; not all drivers are signed and SecureBoot doesn't work with all of them as a result.

Comment: Thanks. So on Windows all the drivers are signed ?

Comment: They're supposed to be.  Doesn't mean they are, and sometimes you need to disable Secure Boot for drivers on Windows as well.  It's usually more rare a case, but it can happen.  Especially with open-source drivers where many people contribute to it and the people running the project aren't going to be paying money for code-signing things.

Comment: thanks for sharing this information, this actually solved my issue on an Asus VivoBook laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with open source drivers is that not all of them are "signed" drivers.  "Signed" drivers are drivers which have been signed with a digital identity code signing certificate to indicate the legitimacy of the developers.

Many open source drivers don't have this digital signature (it's not the easiest thing in the world to get a code signing certificate, and it's not really that cheap - $170/year *and* it requires you to provide detailed documentation that you as a business entity are real and can be considered a business or organization under the law), and as a result SecureBoot can't properly permit them, because they're not 'signed' and 'secured' drivers.

In those cases, you have to disable SecureBoot.  In Windows, *most* drivers are signed, except for open source ones which you install separately, which aren't always signed.

Regardless of the OS, SecureBoot requires signed drivers.  It's just an extra layer of security, so unless you're installing suspicious drivers and such all the time, it's up to you whether you keep SecureBoot on or off, and if hardware you're using *isn't* signed and you *need* the hardware because it's critical, then you've got no choice but to disable SecureBoot, or sign the drivers yourself (which for various reasons might not be doable).

Having to disable SecureBoot for Linux installs and drivers is also not uncommon, either, as this is and was a common occurrence ever since SecureBoot was initially introduced.

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep the Secure Boot active, and sign yourself the driver, [adding your own Machine Owner Key](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot#MOK_-_Machine_Owner_Key).

Comment: This is a solution I overheard, I don't have the ubuntu computer to test it myself. So anyone, feel free to create a new answer based on the link above, and to earn those reps.